# Cats Writer Vector is empty

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I wrote this simple program in my attempt to learn how Cats Writer works

```
import cats.data.Writer
import cats.syntax.applicative._
import cats.syntax.writer._
import cats.instances.vector._

object WriterTest extends App {
   type Logged2[A] = Writer[Vector[String], A]
   Vector("started the program").tell
   val output1 = calculate1(10)
   val foo = new Foo()
   val output2 = foo.calculate2(20)
   val (log, sum) = (output1 + output2).pure[Logged2].run
   println(log)
   println(sum)

   def calculate1(x : Int) : Int = {
      Vector("came inside calculate1").tell
      val output = 10 + x
      Vector(s"Calculated value ${output}").tell
      output
   }
}

class Foo {
   def calculate2(x: Int) : Int = {
      Vector("came inside calculate 2").tell
      val output = 10 + x
      Vector(s"calculated ${output}").tell
      output
   }
}
```

The program works and the output is

```
> run-main WriterTest
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/Cats/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Running WriterTest 
Vector()
50
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Jan 21, 2017 8:14:19 AM
```

But why is the vector empty? Shouldn't it contain all the strings on which I used the "tell" method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `tell` on your `Vector`s, each time you create a `Writer[Vector[String], Unit]`. However, you never actually *do* anything with your `Writer`s, you just discard them. Further, you call `pure` to create your final `Writer`, which simply creates a `Writer` with an empty `Vector`. You have to *combine* the writers together in a chain that carries your value and message around.

```
type Logged[A] = Writer[Vector[String], A]

val (log, sum) = (for {
  _ <- Vector("started the program").tell
  output1 <- calculate1(10)
  foo = new Foo()
  output2 <- foo.calculate2(20)
} yield output1 + output2).run

def calculate1(x: Int): Logged[Int] = for {
  _ <- Vector("came inside calculate1").tell
  output = 10 + x
  _ <- Vector(s"Calculated value ${output}").tell
} yield output

class Foo {
  def calculate2(x: Int): Logged[Int] = for {
    _ <- Vector("came inside calculate2").tell
    output = 10 + x
    _ <- Vector(s"calculated ${output}").tell
  } yield output
}
```

Note the use of `for` notation. The definition of `calculate1` is really

```
def calculate1(x: Int): Logged[Int] = Vector("came inside calculate1").tell.flatMap { _ =>
  val output = 10 + x
  Vector(s"calculated ${output}").tell.map { _ => output }
}
```

`flatMap` is the monadic *bind* operation, which means it understands how to take two monadic values (in this case `Writer`) and join them together to get a new one. In this case, it makes a `Writer` containing the concatenation of the logs and the value of the one on the right.

Note how there are no side effects. There is no global state by which `Writer` can remember all your calls to `tell`. You instead make many `Writer`s and join them together with `flatMap` to get one big one at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your example code is that you're not using the result of the `tell` method.

If you take a look at its signature, you'll see this:

```
final class WriterIdSyntax[A](val a: A) extends AnyVal {

   def tell: Writer[A, Unit] = Writer(a, ())

}
```

it is clear that `tell` returns a `Writer[A, Unit]` result which is immediately discarded because you didn't assign it to a value.

The proper way to use a `Writer` (and any monad in Scala) is through its `flatMap` method. It would look similar to this:

```
println(
  Vector("started the program").tell.flatMap { _ =>
    15.pure[Logged2].flatMap { i =>
      Writer(Vector("ended program"), i)
    }
  }
)
```

The code above, when executed will give you this:

```
WriterT((Vector(started the program, ended program),15))
```

As you can see, both messages and the int are stored in the result.

Now this is a bit ugly, and Scala actually provides a better way to do this: for-comprehensions. For-comprehension are a bit of syntactic sugar that allows us to write the same code in this way:

```
println(
  for {
    _ <- Vector("started the program").tell
    i <- 15.pure[Logged2]
    _ <- Vector("ended program").tell
  } yield i
)
```

Now going back to your example, what I would recommend is for you to change the return type of `compute1` and `compute2` to be `Writer[Vector[String], Int]` and then try to make your application compile using what I wrote above.